# Ng-model not updating the value in the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form like this :

```
 <form name="UserForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="setUser()" >

   <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="add a firstname.." class="form-control input-md" ng-model="user.firstname"  required>

       <button id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showMessage = 'false'" ng-disabled="UserForm.$invalid">Save</button>
  </form>
```

and in my controller :

```
customModule2.controller('UserController',function ($state, $stateParams, $location, $log,$http, $scope, userFactory , appSettings) {

 $scope.user = {};
 $scope.setUser = function () {
    if($scope.UserForm.$valid) {
        userFactory.addUser($scope.user)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log("controller set : " + this.user.firstname);
                $scope.addMessage = data;
                $log.log('');

            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("user firstname : " + $scope.user.firstname);
             });
        $scope.UserForm.$setPristine();
    }
 };
)};
```

Now when I type the firstname I can see it being added but when I check in the console the value in the controller is null.

Any help would be appreciated.thanks

**EDIT :**

I have this controller and it's nearly the same code and it works well :

```
customModule2.controller('ProjectController',function ($state, $stateParams, $location, $log,$http, $scope, projectFactory , appSettings) {
    $scope.project = {};
    $scope.setProject = function () {
    if($scope.ProjectForm.$valid) {
        projectFactory.addProject($scope.project)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.addMessage = data;
                console.log('here' + $scope.project.name);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.addMessage = "Erreur lors de l'ajout : " + data + ' ' + status;
                console.log('here');
                $log.log(data.error + '' + status);
            });
        $scope.showMessage = true;
        $scope.ProjectForm.$setPristine();
    }
    };
```

Could it be a `$scope` problem ?

Comment: You are logging user.cin not user.firstname

Comment: There are syntax errors in your provided code . are you sure this is what you have in your code ?

Comment: yep that's my code and I've update the code, "it's a snippet"

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `success(...)` and `error(...)` functions have a different scope (a different `$scope` variable). To fix this, you can cache the value.

```
customModule2.controller('UserController',function ($state, $stateParams, $location, $log,$http, $scope, userFactory , appSettings) {

    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.setUser = function () {
       var firsName = $scope.user.firstname;
       if($scope.UserForm.$valid) {
           userFactory.addUser($scope.user)
               .success(function (data) {
                   console.log("controller set : " + this.user.cin);
                   $scope.addMessage = data;
                   $log.log('');

               })
               .error(function (data, status) {
                   console.log("user firstname : " firstName);
                });
           $scope.UserForm.$setPristine();
       }
    };
)};
```

Comment: Well I have a form, so I have a lot of data, I need to do that for all the data ?o.O plus I have the same code in another controller/form and it works fine...

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid Yes but that is not the usual way of doing it. Since you're using a factory and you're passing the form data to it (the `$scope.user` object) you should create this factory in such a way that it won't be necessary to access the form inside the `success(...)` or `error(...)` functions.

Comment: Thank you for your responses but I'm not convinced that this is THE answer cause As I said I have the SAME code in another controller/form and it works fine ( when I say the same I just changed project variable with user that's all),

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to print in the console your username using:

```
console.log("controller set : ", $scope.user.firstname);
```

The concatenation `console.log("controller set : " + $scope.user.firstname)`tries to transform your `user.firstname` Object into a String.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it should work even with `$scope.user.firstname`